# Is it possible to bypass sorting of localdata when using grouping in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have client-side data (local data) always sorted, and I don't want jqgrid to re-sort the data for grouping (like server-side sorted data behaviour-- groupDataSorted = true).

Is it possible to bypass/disable sorting of data before grouping in jqGrid? In other words, are there any way to use groupDataSorted = true, for editurl= "clientArray"?

```
datatype: 'local',
data: mydata, 
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [10, 20,30,40],
pager: '#pager',
gridview: true,
sortname: 'invdate',
viewrecords: true,
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ['name'],
    groupSummary: [true],
    groupColumnShow: false,
    groupText: ['<b>{0}-{1} items</b>'],
},
editurl: 'clientArray'
```

Comment: I don't understand how local data be always sorted. Do you have `sortable: false` in all columns? You wrote about `editurl:  "clientArray"`. Do you mean `datatype: 'local'`? The jqGrid which you use con clear the questions about the configurations (the jqGrid parameters) which you use.

Comment: well yes, "datatype: local", what I mean is the data is not retrieved from serverside. Think it like that, there is an other widget on the browserpage and that retrives/populates the data and passes the data to the jqgrid at client side.